# Only display message when browser is not Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is actually my first question on Stack Overflow, so i'm quite excited.

**Question:**
I made a game that requires Flash to operate. I would like to show a message to visitors of the website with a browser that is not Chrome.

It would be a string: "If the game is not loaded correctly, try using Google Chrome".

If you guys would know a way to show this message when not visiting with Google Chrome (because that would be a bit redundant), I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you already searched for existing solutions on this? *What have you tried?* A quick search I made on StackOverflow and Google showed many possible solutions for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect browser and if it's `chrome` make it hide:

```js
if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
$('#Msg').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Msg">Hello!!!</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will also match Microsoft Edge, since it has 'Chrome' in the user agent string. Example: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240`